# Format tweet on the client side with javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter

To document some recent events I saved all tweets including a special hashtag. Now I have about 50.000 tweets which I want to publish. To save bandwidth and server load I want just want to send the raw tweet text to the client and then render it with javascript (linking hashtags, useranames and urls).

Is there already javascript library which is able to parse and create a html representation from a raw tweet?

Comment: The text element which you get via the json api.

Comment: There isn't much to write to get what You need. It might be faster to reinvent the wheel than to learn how somebody else's one works, You know...

Comment: you can change the tweet raw text to html on server side using any language ;-)

Comment: I'm looking for something like this as well -- Twitter enforces [tweet display requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements) so it'd be nice to not have to start from scratch... hm... maybe I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

[`twitterlib.render()`](https://github.com/remy/twitterlib/blob/master/twitterlib.js#L369) looks like a good start... assuming you have parsed JSON tweet data:

```
<script src="twitterlib.js"></script>

<script>
    var parsed_tweet_data = getTweetData(...); // get a Tweet JS object...
    var html = twitterlib.render(parsed_tweet_data);
    // Do something with the rendered html now...
</script>
```

Here's a [twitterlib walkthrough](http://www.slideshare.net/remy.sharp/twitterlibjs#btnNext) on SlideShare.net (slide 17 has a demo.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Twitter [oembed API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/oembed)? It basically lets you request the "official" embedded tweet HTML programmatically using an anonymous API (no authentication required). This would at least make it easy to meet the [display requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements) without reinventing the wheel. You can even do this client side, depending on your use case.

I'm grappling with this same issue, so let us know what you try and how it works for your project.